# Events combination SmartGWT

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, tree, smartgwt

I'm working on Java, SmartGWT 2.5 & Mozilla FF 3.6.x. I'm using Tree, TreeGrid & TreeNode in my application. I need to drag a node and while dragging I have to see the other nodes  on which mouse will pass with changed background color. I tried with dragStart, dragStop, onCellOver, onCellOut and dragMove, but maybe I don't make a good combination of them. So, how can be these events combinated to get what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [DropOverHandler](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee-latest/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/Canvas.html#addDropOverHandler%28com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.DropOverHandler%29) on the target widget (a TreeGrid in this case).

You'll then need to use one of the many available styling APIs (probably getCellCSSText()) so that it returns different results while the mouse remains over the target grid, and call markForRedraw() on the grid from DropOver so that your new styling is applied.

Overriding [willAcceptDrop()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee-latest/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/Canvas.html#willAcceptDrop%28%29) is how you tell the system whether dropping on a particular row is allowed (affects the mouse cursor).

Detect the mouse exiting the grid via the DropOut event, and call markForRedraw() again there.

Comment: thank you.But now I have a problem getting the target. I mean, it should be casted from Canvas to Node: Node _parent = event.getTarget(), this event.getTarget() returns Canvas and I do you know how to cast it?

Comment: event.getTarget() is going to return the widget that is the target of the event (a TreeGrid, subclass of Canvas, in this case), and that is not a TreeNode and cannot be cast to TreeNode.  But I can't tell what you want a TreeNode for and in which event, so try re-posting as a new question with more detail.